# redirect whole directory to another

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect whole directory to another
like :

```
http://test.com/en/file1.php
http://test.com/en/file2.php
http://test.com/en/file3.php
http://test.com/en/file4.php
http://test.com/en/directory
```

to

```
http://test.com/fa/file1.php
http://test.com/fa/file2.php
http://test.com/fa/file3.php
http://test.com/fa/file4.php
http://test.com/fa/directory
```

how ?

Answer (score 0):

You can place this line as first line in your root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/(.*)$ /fr/$1
```